# What's the difference between using nested routes vs. accepts_nested_attributes_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations, nested-attributes

I may be confusing the two entirely, but I'm seeing that forms can facilitate associations using an array argument based on nested routes, ex:

```
<%= form_for [@project, @task]...
```

or using the `fields_for` helper if the parent class `accepts_nested_nested_attributes_for` the child.

What's the difference / trade-offs between these approaches?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I didn't find the answers given to be as clear as I had hoped, so after doing a bit more research I discovered an answer that satisfied me and so I figured I'd share it with others.

**Nested routes approach**

Basically, the nested routes approach is useful when you're presenting a form for a child model as a single form in it's own right.  In other words, if you have a blog with a Post model with a Comment model as it's child, you can use nested routes to present the form for the child such that submitting that form will let rails do its magic in terms of associating the child with the parent.

**Nested attributes approach**

The accepts_nested_attributes_for method on the other hand, is more aptly used to present a form that while taking on the appearance of a single form, is really multiple forms merged together with a single submit button.

So to summarize, the **nested routes approach** deals with one model in single form (albeit associated with a parent model), while the **nested attribute approach** deals with multiple models in a single form.

The difference might be subtle to newcomers, but meaningful enough to understand.

Hope this helps others who had questions about this.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This is child model form:

```
<%= form_for [@project, @task] ... %>
```

where you submiting `Task` for the existent `Project`.

Here `@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])` and `@task = Task.new` according to [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) or `@task = Task.find(params[:id])` if you're updating existing task.

This is used in the parent model form:

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :task do |builder| %>
    <% # ... %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

where you can create or update both objects at once. `Task` attributes will be pass in the `params[:project][:task_attributes]` with task `id` if you're updating objects.

Comment: So the first form_for will automatically generate the hidden_field with :project_id for Task. Right?

Comment: Nope. `project_id` will be included in the path in the `action` attribute of the `form` and will be recognized in controller due to nested routes specified in the `routes.rb`

Comment: ok so the first form_for just assign the poject_id to the url like this `/projecs/:project_id/tasks`

Comment: So you're saying the nested routes pattern is used for creating child objects when the parent already exists, where as the accepts_nested_attributes_for method is best when creating both the parent and child at once?  What about updating?

Comment: Absolutely the same. See my updated anwser. Sorry didn't mention `update` before.

Comment: So I guess the natural follow up question is... why use the nested routes approach?  If you can create and update children using accepts_nested_attributes_for, why not use only this for all cases?